# Sharing Internet Connection

Tags: internet-connection

I have a Cable Internet (Assigned IP etc) to connect to internet and I want to connect another computer to same line of cable as well. Both in Same room. Any suggestion, affordable solution please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common approach is to get a wifi or ethernet router.

Connect this device to the cable internet device, then connect your computer to the wifi/ethernet router.

Take a look at http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/homenetworking/a/homenetguide.htm

Comment: Ethernet Router! gotcha...gotta go to buy one. :)

Comment: I'd recommend a combined ethernet/wifi router.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend buying a [Linksys WRT120N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/EU/en/products/WRT120N), this one is less than 50US$. There are other brands that are even less expensive, but I prefer Linksys.

There is one port for the connection to the cable modem, and there are 4 ports for computers (alternatively you can connect other computers via wireless)