# Connect 2 computers to internet (1 ip) via switch

Tags: windows, internet-connection, switch

How to connect 2 computers to internet with a switch if ISP gave me 1 IP?
Obviously, if I set the same IP on both PCs, one of them will not connect.
Both computers are running Windows 7 (but answers for XP or 8 will be usable too).

**UPDATE :**
Switch model is [TP-Link TL-SF1005D](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-SF1005D). I can't assign an IP to my switch, it hasn't that option.
It's a cable broadband internet, but I have no access to the router. All I got is a RJ45 cable directly to home. So I can't just plug the second cable directly to the router.

Comment: You can't just use a hub as a "splitter", you need a NAT router of some kind.  Windows can act as a router.  Search for Windows Internet Connection Sharing.  Otherwise please edit and update this question to include what research you've done, what you've tried already, and what the results were.

Comment: Yes I know. I think about connecting one of them to internet, and set another PC's gateway to it, but not sure if it will work. And I'd like to receive an answer like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing Internet Connection](http://superuser.com/questions/140036/sharing-internet-connection)

Comment: Some more details about the device that you use to connect to your ISP could be useful. Is it a cable modem? A DSL modem? A mobile internet modem? What cable inputs does it have? Maybe the exact model would help, too.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez question updated

Comment: @techie007 , that question is not about connecting by using switch or at least it has no usable answer for this case.

Comment: No problem with that, @Jet. Any WAN to LAN RJ45 router **should be configurable** to replicate the data configuration you have from your ISP. Or so I think. Please tell me what kind of data do you have: IP, NetMask, Gateway, some(s) DNS(s) and any thing more? Maybe some username? MAC restriction for your computer, maybe?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez to configure, I must set IP,Gateway,Mask,DNS they gave. No MAC, username and password.

Comment: Sorry i only know how to do this on linux. You need 2 ip addresses simultaneously on the server PC, one dhcp and the other static (i think this is not even possible in windows).

Answer (score 1):

You only need one IP address when you use a NAT router.  I expect your ISP gave you a NAT router, so you should be able to connect both machines to the ethernet ports on that.

If your router only has one ethernet port, which is pretty unusual for home routers these days, you can connect a 'switch' to it.  Switches look the same as hubs, but are more advanced.  It is rare to find hubs these days.

[This is an example of a switch.](http://www.netgear.co.uk/images/pdf/GS105v3_GS108v3_DS_27Apr1118-4903.pdf)  You may as well get a gigabit speed switch rather than a slower one.

Comment: I have no direct access to router. I connect the cable they gave me to my switch and connect PCs to switch, but how to configure computers? (Question was updated)

Comment: @Jet You shouldn't have to do anything if the router has DHCP enabled.  If you have messed around with the settings, the easiest thing to do is delete the network connection and start again.  Don't think about IP addresses as the default configuration usually gets everything working automatically.

Comment: Default configurations doesn't work. But I think about an alternative way like this http://superuser.com/questions/735162/connect-2-computers-to-internet-1-ip-via-switch/735170?noredirect=1#comment944379_735162

Comment: @Jet In that case look up Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) in Windows.  As long as one of your computers has a gigabit NIC, you won't need a crossover ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution: use a **WAN to LAN router** that has **RJ45 jack** in both WAN and LAN sides.
An example: Buffalo [WHR-HP-GN](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/en/products/network-devices/wireless-adapters-converters/airstationtm/airstation-trade-n-technology-150mbps-cable-router/) (note the backside, with WAN RJ45 in blue color).

- Connect the WAN (blue, in the example) RJ45 cable to your ISP router [RJ45 cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C).
- Connect the rest of computers to the LAN (black, in the example) RJ45 side of the router (Buffalo WHR-HP-GN in the example).

The rest of network configurations, assuming you have DHCP enabled, should be done automatically, unless your ISP gave you some specific configuration data.

EDIT: Here is the example for configuring this router (firmware DD-WRT, very common) with:

- IP WAN: `192.168.11.230`
- Gateway WAN: `192.168.11.1`
- NetMask WAN: `255.255.255.0`
- DNS: `80.58.0.33`
- IP LAN: `192.168.22.1`
- NetMask LAN: `255.255.255.0`

[image: DD-WRT router with both WAN and LAN static IP]

WAN is your ISP data, and LAN is your (future) home network. Your two computers can be set to DHCP, and the router (look at `DHCP Server Enable`) will assign them an IP in the range `192.168.22.x`, starting at `192.168.22.2` for the first that you will turn on.
If you buy a non DD-WRT router, the configuration will be similar.
You will not need your TP-Link switch with this config. If you still prefer to use it instead of a router, I suggest the "Share Internet Connection" from Windows 7 capability, but the you will need the first computer (sharing internet) always running for the second to have internet.

Comment: ISP gave me specific configuration, and router DHCP is not enabled